# Remove 'View All Category' link from RWD theme's navigation

Tags: menu, rwd, rwd-theme

How do I remove the View All link from the menu in rwd theme?

This is the current set of categories I have and how I want it to show in the menu

Category 1
-- Subcategory 1
---- Subcategory 1
-- Subcategory 2

Category 2
-- Subcategory 1

When using rwd it shows the menu like this

Category 1
--View All Category 1
-- Subcategory 1
---- View All Subcategory 1
---- Subcategory
-- Subcategory 2

Category 2
-- Subcategory 1

I've tried searching but can't find a solution to this.

Comment: Reid Blomquist your answer just excellent .. works like charm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To do this you'll first want to (if you haven't already) create a custom template directory within the RWD design package. This avoids re or overwriting your default templates that live in `magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template`.

For the sake of example we'll create `magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/custom/template`

The specific template we're going to be editing is the topmenu `renderer.phtml` - which resides at `magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml`. To extend this file properly, create a matching directory structure within the `magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/custom/template` directory we just created - you should end up with a directory that looks like this: `magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/custom/template/page/html/topmenu`

Once your topmenu template directory has been created, copy the `renderer.phtml` file from `rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu` into the `rwd/custom/template/page/html/topmenu` directory you just created.

This file should contain the following code at ~ lines 62 - 71:

```
    if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
    $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
    $html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'">';
    $html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';
    $html .=             $this->__('View All ') . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
    $html .=         '</a>';
    $html .=     '</li>';
    $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
```

In your copied file, you'll want to remove or comment out the mid-section so that you're left with:

```
    if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
    $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
    $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
```

Once you've saved your file you can go into adminhtml -> System -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> Themes and set the field "Templates" to the value "custom" -> Save Config and then clear cache.

You should now no longer see the "View All XXX" portion of your sites navigation!

Comment: This fixed the issue. I came across a similar post but that didn't explain about creating custom directories or clearing the cache.

Answer (score -2):

You can also add this CSS somewhere (like styles.css)

```
.view-all {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: hiding something with css doesn't actually remove it, it just hides it